# Mean Deviation about mean for Poisson Distribution?

Tags: poisson-distribution

Please help on how would we solve the summation while deriving mean deviation about mean for Poisson Distribution.

Comment: Is this the "mean absolute deviation" or the "mean square deviation"?

Answer (score 1):

For the absolute mean deviation of $X \sim Poi(\lambda)$,

$$\mathbf{E}_\lambda|X - \lambda| = 2\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^{[\lambda]+1}}{[\lambda]!} = 2 \lambda \mathbf{P}_\lambda(X = [\lambda])$$

where $[\lambda]$ is the integer part of $\lambda$. [Here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeanDeviation.html) is a quick reference for this kind of results, and here is the original proof if you are interested.

[Ramasubban, T. A. "The mean difference and the mean deviation of some discontinuous distributions." Biometrika 45.3/4 (1958): 549-556.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2333200)