# Expectation of the absolute difference between two i.i.d. Poisson variables?

Tags: probability-distributions, reference-request, expected-value

If $X\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$, it is [known](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2418626/75808) that
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X-\lambda|] = \frac{2e^{-\lambda} \lambda^{\lfloor \lambda\rfloor +1}}{\lfloor \lambda\rfloor!} \operatorname*{\sim}_{\lambda\to\infty} \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}\lambda}
$$

Based on this, it is not hard to show, via Jensen's inequality, that if $X,Y\sim\mathrm{Poisson}(\lambda)$ are independent,
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X-\lambda|] \leq \mathbb{E}[|X-Y|] \leq 2\cdot \mathbb{E}[|X-\lambda|]
$$
which gives that $\mathbb{E}[|X-Y|] = \Theta(\sqrt{\lambda})$ as $\lambda\to\infty$. Moreover, the exact leading constant in the $\Theta(\cdot)$ is between $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ and $2\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$. One can even refine the upper bound by Cauchy—Schwarz to get
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X-\lambda|] \leq \mathbb{E}[|X-Y|] \leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}[(X-Y)^2]} = \sqrt{2\lambda}
$$
so we know that the right asymptotic constant is between $\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$ and $\sqrt{2}$.

Based on numerical evidence (see below), it looks like the right answer should be
$$
\mathbb{E}[|X-Y|] \operatorname*{\sim}_{\lambda\to\infty} \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sqrt{\lambda}
$$

> Is this result known? Is there a proof available somewhere?

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$Z=X-Y$ follows the [Skellam distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skellam_distribution) which has probability mass function
$$ p(Z=k) = e^{-2\lambda}I_{|k|}(2\lambda), $$
where $I_{\alpha}$ is the [modified Bessel function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions) of the first kind.
Thus we need to compute the infinite sum $2e^{-x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kI_k(x)$ where $x=2\lambda$. Since we have [the following recurrence relation](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.29#i):
$$ kI_k(x) = \frac{x}{2}(I_{k-1}(x)-I_{k+1}(x)), $$
the partial sum of the series can be simplified as:
$$ 2\sum_{k=1}^{N} kI_k(x) = x(I_0(x)+I_1(x))-x(I_N(x)+I_{N+1}(x)).$$
We have an [asymptotic formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.41#i) for $I_N(x)$ as $N\to\infty$:
$$ I_N(x) \sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi N}}\left(\frac{ex}{2N}\right)^N \underset{N\to\infty}{\to} 0. $$
Finally, we use the [asymptotic formula](https://dlmf.nist.gov/10.40#i) $I_k(x)\sim \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{2\pi x}}$ as $x\to\infty$:
\begin{align*}2e^{-x}\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} kI_k(x) = xe^{-x}(I_0(x)+I_1(x)) &\underset{x\to\infty}{\sim} x\cdot\frac{2}{\sqrt{2\pi x}} \\ 
&= \sqrt{\frac{2x}{\pi}} \\
&= \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\sqrt{\lambda}.
\end{align*}

Comment: Wonderful! This is perfect.

Comment: In the last displayed formula the sum should go up to $\infty$ and not $N$.

Comment: @Gary Fixed. Thanks!